# Get code of Pro PHP MVC book by Chris Pitt

Tags: php, model-view-controller, frameworks

I have read the book till chapter 14: Registration and login but whenever I try to run the application i get the following error

I have uploaded the [Github Repo](https://github.com/faizanayubi/SwiftMVC)

If anyone who has the code for the book please share

> ( ! ) Strict standards: Non-static method Framework\Core::initialize()
>   should not be called statically in
>   C:\wamp\www\SwiftMVC\public\index.php on line 8
>
> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: this in
>   C:\wamp\www\SwiftMVC\framework\core.php on line 14
>
> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message
>   'Passed array does not specify an existing static method (first array
>   member is not a valid class name or object)' in
>   C:\wamp\www\SwiftMVC\framework\core.php on line 14 ( ! )
>   LogicException: Passed array does not specify an existing static
>   method (first array member is not a valid class name or object) in
>   C:\wamp\www\SwiftMVC\framework\core.php on line 14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The publisher only offers the source code separated in each chapter.

In case you don't already know it can be found under ...

http://www.apress.com/9781430241645

Open the tab 'Source Code/Downloads'.

Answer (score 0):

I have read the book Pro PHP MVC by Chris Pitt, there are 2 things i am not sure about- 
1. The Core class and how autoloading of classes is done.
2. ArrayMethods::last isn't defined anywhere, my guess is that it is simply returning the last element but not sure of it.